# How can I detect if an user has stopped walking using C# in my windows store app?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

I need to do this for my app, but I'm not sure how. Currently  I'm trying to achieve it using Geolocator and a Timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare a Geolocator with a fixed ReportInterval
2. Store the locations
3. With the help of these methods compare current with stored location to detect movement

   ```
   public const double EARTH_RADIUS_M = 6371000

   private static double ToRad(double val)
   {
       return val * (Math.PI / 180);
   }

   public static double GetDistanceM(double lat0, double lng0, double lat1, double lng1)
   {
       double dLat = ToRad(lat1 - lat0);
       double dLon = ToRad(lng1 - lng0);

       double a = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(dLat / 2), 2) +
                  Math.Cos(ToRad(lat0)) * Math.Cos(ToRad(lat1)) *
                  Math.Pow(Math.Sin(dLon / 2), 2);

       double c = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sqrt(1 - a));

       double distance = EARTH_RADIUS_M * c;
       return distance;
   }
   ```

   4. Considerations for windows 10:

      ```
      private async void StartLocationExtensionSession()
      {
          session = new ExtendedExecutionSession();
          session.Description = "Location Tracker";
          session.Reason = ExtendedExecutionReason.LocationTracking;
          var result = await session.RequestExtensionAsync();
      }
      ```
   5. Considerations for Windows Phone 8:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662935(v=vs.105).aspx

6. Be happy with your new dynamic MovementThreshold ;)!

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer!! It will help me much in my project!! (Y)